# Android - play video saved from raw assets to local storage using implicit intent failing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, android-assets

I have a **file in my raw assets** directory which I am trying to save to shared phone storage that will **allow other apps to open and view this video**.

Basic code to copy file from assets to local storage and generate intent

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// using getFilesDir() below causes this error: 
File videoFile = new File(getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1], "talking.mp4");

// check if we have already copied file over
if (!videoFile.exists()) {

    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.talking);
        boolean newFile = videoFile.createNewFile();
        if (!newFile) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create file");
        }
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + videoFile, e);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to copy talking.mp4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and getting the file using the [FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context, String, File)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) and creating the intent following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Messaging):

```
Uri uri =  FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName(), videoFile);

// type of file to view
in.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");

// ask some other app to deal with it
startActivity(in);
```

in addition, the following is required in my **manifest**:

```
<application ... >
    //...
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${getPackageName()}"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider>  
</application>
```

next, to define the paths mentioned above in the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider):

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_files_data" path="." />
    <external-files-path name="my_files_ext_data" path="." />
    <external-path name="my_files_ext" path="." />
</paths>
```

**Question:**

When selecting e.g. VLC for Android as the file to handle the intent, the app doesn't play the video. If I try playing it with Google Photos, it loads forever.

This shows my there is something wrong - however I am not quite sure why this isn't working. Is it related to app permissions accessing content root of another app?

Comment: Try to copy the file to public directory, It may help you to identify whether it's permission issue or code issue

Comment: Unless the video is very short, `byte[] data = new byte[is.available()]` is going to crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`. I also recommend making `os` be a `FileOutputStream` and doing `os.flush();` and `os.getFD().sync();` before `os.close();`. Have you used Device File Explorer in Android Studio to copy the video off your device and onto your development machine, to ensure that your copy is faithful?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tested it on my local machine (copied from the location I copied the resource to), and it plays 100% start to finish. The video is 2min duration with size 3.99Mb. I think I should create an entirely new app that accepts this video intent and see what the problem is...

Comment: @CommonsWare this entire ruse is to allow a video file (in raw assets) to be played via an implicit intent w/o using deprecated methods i.e. copying to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`